# Google oauth2 login in spring boot, null refreshToken, failing in remote server, working in localhost

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, google-oauth, google-signin

I have a working code in java 11 with spring security and google oauth login

```
@GetMapping("/google/integration")
public String googleIntegracionUsuario(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("google") OAuth2AuthorizedClient user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("\n\n RefreshToken: " + user.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue());
    System.out.println("\n\n AccessToken: " + user.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
    return "hello user";
}
```

In @Configuration

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/google/integration").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(
                        this.clientRegistrationRepository));
    }
```

In CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver

```
public class CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver implements OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver {
    private final OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver;

    public CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {

        this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver =
                new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, "/oauth2/authorization");
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
        return authorizationRequest != null ? customAuthorizationRequest(authorizationRequest) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request, String clientRegistrationId) {
        final OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request, clientRegistrationId);
        return authorizationRequest != null ? customAuthorizationRequest(authorizationRequest) : null;
    }

    private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest customAuthorizationRequest(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest) {

        Map<String, Object> additionalParameters = new LinkedHashMap<>(authorizationRequest.getAdditionalParameters());
        additionalParameters.put("access_type", "offline");

        return OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.from(authorizationRequest)
                .additionalParameters(additionalParameters)
                .build();
    }

}
```

and in .properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=clientIdValue
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=clientSecret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar,email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly
```

The problem is that when testing in localhost everything runs smooth, but when uploading the project to a remote server the refresh token comes as NULL!

i have no domain for the remote server, but i have edited the /etc/hosts to give an alias to the  public ip of the remote server, AND i have added that alias to the url redirects in the google console developer

In the remote server the login is working properly and the user actually logs in with his/her google account, actually i can get a working accessToken of the user in the remote server, but the refresh token is nowhere to be found, the value just comes as null!

```
System.out.println("\n\n AccessToken: " + uuser.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
//prints: AccessToken: 'AccessToken value' in localhost and remoteServer
```

```
System.out.println("\n\n AccessToken: " + user.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue());
//prints: RefreshToken: 'RefreshToken value' in localhost
//Throws NullPointerException in remoteServer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that the refresh token in the remote server gets the value only the first time the user logs in, and that is an expected behaviour of the oauth2 framework.
But i don't know why i consistently get the refresh token every time in the localhost, and that's what got me confused, i guess it's because it is not bounded to a specific url

Comment: Could you kindly provide the reference or source of your discovery, thanks in advance.

Comment: When you log in first time Google stores in your profile access to your app. When you revoke that access and log again you will get again refresh token. On localhost you run every time new instance and google see it as a new app that's why you get each time refresh token and only once on your dev environment